# Does Azure Storage Tables have RowKey individually indexed to take advantage in subpartition queries?

Tags: indexing, azure, azure-table-storage

I need to know if the Azure Storage Tables have indexed the RowKey separately from the PartitionKey in order to do a query of this kind...

Assumption: My table have Forum Posts having PartitionKey = UserEMail, RowKey = PostInstant. So, I want to query like this...

```
SELECT data FROM forum WHERE PartitionKey="user@company.com" AND RowKey < DateLimit;
```

(Note: I know that the PostInstant should be written "inversed" to take advantage of ascending sort and thus obtain it in descending order, that's not the point).

As I understand, by explicitly indicating the PartitionKey the query is well going on the path of performance, but after that... will the RowKey be intelligently used to a) give the results sorted and b) stop the scan after reached the DateLimit?

Or, in other words, Does the Azure Storage Table indexing applies to the concatenation of PartitionKey+RowKey, thus only be useful for exact row matching and full table sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the query that you have written is as efficient as you can write it against Azure tables and it should make use of indexes for both the `PartitionKey` and the `RowKey`.

Your results are guaranteed to come back in `PartitionKey` then `RowKey` order.

Answer (score 2):

The PartitionKey and RowKey are currently the only indexed attributes you can use.  However, you are only using one in your question.  So, your query will search the entire PartitionKey 'user@company.com' without any further index.  If it is a small partition, this might not be a big deal.  If it is a big one, then you should also use the RowKey.  Note, that while you are specifying an attribute called 'PostInstant', that is not the same as the RowKey.  You must specifically query on RowKey (even if it is same as another column name).

So your query would be more like this:

```
ctx.CreateQuery<Foo>('tablename').Where(s => s.PartitionKey == "user@company.com" && s.RowKey.Compare(DateLimit) > 0);
```

I am assuming of course that 'DateLimit' is actually a string formatted date (like ticks).  If you invert the ordering of ticks you would also invert the comparison operator (>).